# IPad Air 2 (cellular) upgrade to 9.3.1 won't run (after "agreeing", takes me to home screen)

Tags: ios, ipad, upgrade

When trying to upgrade to 9.3.1, the terms of service come up for the upgrade, and when clicking agree (twice -- there's two popups about agreeing), I'm redirected to the home screen and nothing else happens. **Note:** I had this problem with 9.3, and at the time, the 9.3 update was not signed, but as of today, [IPSW](https://ipsw.me/) says this device's update is signed and available, yet the problem remains, even after a restart.

A power cable is attached to the device (with ~80% life). I also tried closing all open applications. Still same result.

Any ideas on how to get the update installed?

Comment: I thought Apple re-released the fixed 9.3 for iPad 2?  It should be available now.

Comment: @fbara Just the iPad 2, not the iPad Air 2. This is a duplicate.

Comment: Yep this is a duplicate. I heard about the 9.3 re-release, so assumed it was fixed for ipad air 2. I see from the link on this duplicate post that (as of today, Mar 28 2016), ipad air 2's update is not signed.  Thanks all!

Comment: After trying to install the 9.3.1 update, which is currently active/signed, I still get the same behavior, even after a restart, so I'm reopening this question.  Could something be cached on my device that is causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing via iTunes works (i.e., plug iPad into computer with iTunes running), so I ended up doing that.

For others that run into this problem: you may want to make sure you have enough disk space on your device. I had 32gb, so I know that wasn't my problem.

I suspect my problem had something to do with the 9.3 update arriving, and then Apple unsigning it because of its bugs; and maybe when 9.3.1 came out, my iPad was confused?  *shrugs*